# Aurelia repeat.for access index of item

Tags: aurelia

I have a simple repeat.for:

```
<li repeat.for="item of items">${item}</li>
```

Currently I'm using: `${$parent.items.indexOf(item)}`.
Is there a shorthand, something like {{$index}} in angular?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

There is. Write this:

```
<li repeat.for="item of items">${$index} - ${item}</li>
```

Comment: This is straightforward angularjs to aurelia transition. I can't remember what I did wrong when I first tried it.

Comment: Just a note that this index is zero-based. To get your list to start at 1, use this:
${$index + 1}

Comment: plus one the plus one comment! lol thanks, I was getting this wrong as well.

Comment: Could you please provide the aurelia doc link? thank you