# Aurelia array binding with checkbox selection and element reference disable

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm trying to accomplish the following without the use of extra custom functions:

- Store selected items in a new array
- Only enable the textbox if its respective checkbox has been selected
- Keep track of updated values in new array

Below is a simplified sample of my code:

```
<div repeat.for="item of itemSearch.rates">
  <input type="checkbox" ref="item.$index" model.bind="item" checked.bind="selectedRates">
  <input type="text" disabled.bind="item.$index.checked == false" value.bind="item.total_value">
</div>
```

Currently, with the above, only the `checked.bind` is working. Selected items are stored in my new `selectedRates` array.

However my `disabled.bind` is not being triggered at all.
If I remove `checked.bind` from the checkbox, `disabled.bind` works perfectly.

Also the updated values appear to pull through to the `selectedRates` *sometimes* after submit and the elements have lost focus.
I'm aware that array observation is not officially supported [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501250/aurelia-array-observation-doesnt-react-on-arrayindex-newitem), just something I noticed worth mentioning.

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to get `checked.bind` to work along with the `ref` & `disabled.bind`?

   - [Example with checked.bind](https://gist.run/?id=0c64a1602738774bb7658cf28db726ee)
   - [Example without checked.bind](https://gist.run/?id=670c62155647e16d8be5f8a79772ff34)
2. Any idea why I'm seeing this array observable-like behavior *sometimes*?

**Update**

I found the "observable values" issue to appear intermittently in firebug when logging the `selectedRates`.
When displaying it in html, the value changes are always updated, with both @Fabio's use of the `BindingEngine` implementation as well as my `checked.bind`. Chrome always displays and logs the correct values.
Still no idea why, or if I should be concerned about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the simplest solution I could find. There might be easier ways.

**html**

```
<template>
  <div repeat.for="item of rates">
    <input type="checkbox"  ref="item.check" model.bind="item" change.delegate="updateSelectedRates(item)">
    <input type="text" disabled.bind="item.check.checked" value.bind="item.value">
  </div>

  <br>
  <template repeat.for="rate of selectedRates">${rate.value}</template>
</template>
```

**js**

```
export class App {

  rates =  [ { value: 1 }, {value: 2} ];
  selectedRates = [];

  updateSelectedRates(rate) {
    if (rate.check.checked) {
      this.selectedRates.push(rate);
    } else {
      let index = this.selectedRates.map(rate => rate.value).indexOf(rate.value);
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.selectedRates.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Running example https://gist.run/?id=0c2911d065e9725f6f86f45a2422b009

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Fabio. Adding that `selected` property to my objects will work, but I'd still prefer not to have the custom functions if possible.  Could it perhaps be a bug why `checked.bind` is not working along with the `ref` & `disabled.bind`?

Comment: As for the observable values, I found the issue to only really appear in firebug when logging the selectedRates. When displaying it in html, the value changes are always updated, with both your use of the `BindingEngine` implementation as well as my `checked.bind`. Chrome always displays and logs the correct values.

Comment: It's assigning the array's index to that property [as explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418345/aurelia-repeat-for-access-index-of-item) and works fine with `disabled.bind="item.$index.checked == false"`. Please note the difference between the following examples [with checked.bind](https://gist.run/?id=0c64a1602738774bb7658cf28db726ee) and [without checked.bind](https://gist.run/?id=670c62155647e16d8be5f8a79772ff34)

Comment: Indeed... you're right. I think you should open an issue in the oficial repo

Comment: @JvR I've found an easier solution. See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks @Fabio, I will go with a variation of that for now, I have just changed the function to accept `$event` and then check its target, rather than having another `check` property on my object. [See example here](https://gist.run/?id=cb7a93d18cef07b719d13ce085b86786).

Comment: Oh yes and it does look like a related bug as [reported here.](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/560)

Answer (score 2):

See the docs

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-checkboxes/1

```
<input type="checkbox" model.bind="product.id" checked.bind="selectedProductIds">
```